# Solution of a constrained Laplace equation

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have a Laplace equation in 2D
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 f(x,y) = 0
\end{equation}
It comes from the Fick's law of diffusion at equelibrium. The problem has radial symmetry, then I use polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ and I drop the angular part. Therefore the previous equation becomes:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 f(r)}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{d f(r)}{dr} = 0
\end{equation}

I can easily solve this equation obtaining the solution $f(r) = A \ln(r) + C$ where both $A$ and $C$ are constant. The problem are the constraints
\begin{align}
f(R^*) = 0\\
\lim_{r \to \infty} f(r) = B
\end{align}
where $B$ is a known number. But the solution that I have found can not satisfy the constraint, because $\ln(r)$ is divergent.

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: $r$ can go from 0 to $+\infty$.